# Ugly Numbers- Find 1500th UVA online judge

Tags: java, runtime

Source code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


class Uglynumbers {

/**
 * @param arg
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long[] ugly= new long[1510];
    long inter1,inter2,inter3;
    int count=0;
    boolean found1=false,found2=false,found3=false;

    ugly[0]=1;
    ugly[1]=2;
    ugly[2]=3;
    ugly[3]=5;
    count=4;
    for (int i=1; i<1500;i++)
    {
        found1=found2=found3=false;
        inter1= ugly[i]*2;
        inter2= ugly[i]*3;
        inter3= ugly[i]*5;

        for(int z=count-1;z>=0;z--)
        {
            if((inter1>ugly[z]) && (inter2>ugly[z]) && (inter3>ugly[z]))
                break;
            else
            {
             if(ugly[z]==inter1)
                found1=true;
             if(ugly[z]==inter2)
                found2=true;
             if(ugly[z]==inter3)
                found3=true;
            }

            if( found1 && found2 && found3)
                break;
        }

        if(!found1)
        {

            ugly[count]=inter1;
            count+=1;

        }

        if(!found2)
        {

            ugly[count]=inter2;
            count+=1;

        }

        if(!found3)
        {

            ugly[count]=inter3;
            count+=1;

        }

        Arrays.sort(ugly,0,count);


        if(count>=1500)
            break;

        }


System.out.println("The 1500'th ugly number is "+ ugly[1499]);


System.exit(0);


}

};
```

When I run this code in eclipse its working fine. But when i give it UVA online judge, am getting following run time error: ""136 - Ugly Numbers has failed with verdict Runtime error.
  This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0"."

What am missing in the code?

Comment: We would not know, this runs fine on JVM on Windows. Most people would not be able to provide any information. Perhaps get rid of the last character (the semicolon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it requires the class to be called Main.

http://code.google.com/p/collatz-deandalm/issues/detail?id=13

EDIT:

Entire Java specification:

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=30

> Java Specifications:
>   The Java programs submitted must be in a single source code (not .class) file. Nevertheless, you can add as many classes as you need in this file. All the classes in this file must not be within any package.
>
> All programs must begin in a static main method in a Main class.
>
> Do not use public classes: even Main must be non public to avoid compile error.
>
> Use buffered I/O to avoid time limit exceeded due to excesive flushing.
>
> As a reference, we provide a sample Java code

Get rid of this:

`System.exit(0);`

And change `Uglynumbers` to `Main`.

Comment: Just new to Stack overflow. how to accept the answer? I looking for the option

Comment: @DaveNewton, I was looking at something else. Thanks. Changed.